# I have created graphs plots showing how the shape of this curve varies as the handling time (h) and the attack rate (a) vary but it doesn't seem right

Tags: r, curve

I am trying to how the shape of this curve varies as the handling time (h) and the attack rate (a) vary from the Type II functional response, `f(x) = a*x / 1 + a*h*x`.

This is what I did:

```
##Create function.
    {r,echo=TRUE}
    fr <- function(x, a = 1, h = 1){
      a*x / 1 + a*h*x
    }
    

##Plot with h varying.
    {r,echo=TRUE}
    plot(NA, xlim=c(-5,5), ylim=c(-10,10))
    for (h in c(1:5)){
      curve(expr = fr(x, 1, h), from = -5, to = 5, n = 100, add= TRUE, col = h)
    }
    

##Plot with a varying.
    {r,echo=TRUE}
    plot(NA, xlim=c(-5,5), ylim=c(-10,10))
    for (a in c(1:5)){
      curve(expr = fr(x, a, 1), from = -5, to = 5, n = 100, add= TRUE, col = a)
    }
```

However, I don't understand the graphs. They don't really look like the curves I expected. They don't look like Type II functional response curves.

Comment: I strongly suspect your `f(x)` is missing parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

As @Roland said in the comment, probably the parentheses is missing, here is the difference between the two implementations.

[image]

Comment: That is not what I got when I changed the parentheses and it also doesn't seem quite right. It is supposed to be a Type II functional response curve.